# Spaces in Makefile dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a GNU Make rule that depends on two files with spaces. I do not want to hard-code the names so I would like to escape the names that contain spaces.

```
GS := gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  
DEPENDENCIES := File\ 1.pdf File\ 2.pdf

Final.pdf: $(DEPENDENCIES)
    # $@ corresponds to "Final.pdf", and $^ is an automatic variable
    # that expands to "File" "1.pdf" "File" "2.pdf", however, I would like
    # it to be "File 1.pdf" and "File 2.pdf"
    # Ghostscript complains that "File" cannot be found, "2.pdf"... etc.
    $(GS) -sOutputFile="$@" $^

    # Now, the variable expands to "File 1.pdf File 2.pdf", which does
    # not yield the intended result either.
    $(GS) -sOutputFile="$@" "$^"

    # Ultimate goal is to get make to run the following command:
    #   $(GS) -sOutputFile="Final.pdf" "File 1.pdf" "File 2.pdf"
```

Is there a way to get away with it using plain Make, or do I have to resort to an external tool that will generate the Makefile for me (or another build system)? (e.g. autotools or scons)

Portability is not a requirement, but is a nice-to-have.

Comment: make flat-out cannot handle files with spaces in the name. You cannot get this to work.

Comment: Use a utility that will rename the files prior to invoking make.  I use [this quick hack](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/unixifn).

Comment: Note that autotools (automake in particular) just generates makefiles, so that won't help with this.  You'd have to switch to an entirely different build system like scons etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use automatic variables as `$^` or `$<` since they don't preserve spaces in file names. Nevertheless you can use `$(DEPENDENCIES)`, which contains the escaped spaces:

```
GS := gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  
DEPENDENCIES := File\ 1.pdf File\ 2.pdf

Final.pdf: $(DEPENDENCIES)
    $(GS) -sOutputFile="$@" $(DEPENDENCIES)
```

Checked with GNU Make 3.81